# Mongo single upsert to add or update a field in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I was trying to do something that it would be nice if it was supported, but appears not to be.

I would like to be able to update a record if it exists, and if not set the field to a default value.  Specifically, I am using .AddToSet() to append an object to a list.

This will not work:

```
     UpdateBuilder<TestDocument> update = Update<TestDocument>
        .Set(d => d.UpdatedOn, DateTime.Now)
        .SetOnInsert(d => d.ListOfItems, new List<Item> () {ItemToAdd})
        .AddToSet(d => d.ListOfItems, ItemToAdd);

  TestCollection.Update(query,update, UpdateFlags.Upsert);
```

What I would expect:

On an update just add the record to the end of the existing list.

If it doesn't exist, have it do one of the following:

1. Set the field to the value, and ignore the update.
2. Set the field to the value, and then do the update.  (so, I would change the code to do

   SetOnInsert (d => d.ListOfItems, new List< Item> ())

But instead, it throws an error that the field is specified twice.

I could (and have) fixed this by doing a search first, if not found, do a upsert with the first record.  If that returns 0 documents affected (someone else upserted it.) then I fall back and do the upsert - which of course, is also done if the document exists.

Is there a cleaner way?  Or ideally, doing it in a single command?

Comment: Perhaps you could be a little more clear, as I'm a little confused by the result you are looking for. Could you provide what the collection should look like after an update and also what the collection should look like after an upsert? That way, we can know very clearly what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: In the first case, I would have one of two situations:  1) No record exists at all.  Or 2) a record exists.   If it exists, I want to 'SetOnInsert(...) to add a new item to the list in the document.  If it doesn't, I want add a new document with that new item in the list (ListOfItems) - Not sure how much clearer I can make that

Comment: So, leave off the SetOnInsert. In the case of an upsert, the AddToSet will do exactly what SetOnInsert is doing...

This is why I was confused, because it seemed like your actually wanted different behavior than this default behavior.

Comment: Ah, Awesome!  Thanks - change that to an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetOnInsert is only necessary when you want something to only apply on insert. In this case, you want the AddToSet to apply whether it's an update or an upsert. So, if you just use AddToSet, it will accomplish what you want.